# how to bind data of api into ng-multiselect-dropdown?

Tags: html, angular6, dropdown

I want to bind data into a multi-select dropdown, how it is possible?

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!--
    <select class="form-control custom-selec" formControlName='stoppage_point'>  
        <option *ngFor="let cities of city.data" [(ngValue)]="cities.city">{{cities.city}}</option>  
    </select>
    -->
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
        name="city"
        [placeholder]="'Select City'" 
        [data]="city.data" 
        formControlName="city" 
        [disabled]="disabled" 
        [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

.ts file code:

```
this.http.get(environment.api_url + `/admin/get_only_city/`
).subscribe((data:any[])=> {
  console.log(data);
  this.city = data;
  var i; 
  for(i=0;i<=8;i++){
    console.log(this.city.data[i]['_id']) ;
  }

  this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit:5,
    allowSearchFilter: true
  };
});
```

I want to display all records in a dropdown, but it's not displaying values.

I don't how to bind a particular value in the data, so please can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my [example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-api-call)

You call a webservice and fetch the result data into an array. And this array you push into your dropdownlist.

```
  getData(): void {
    let tmp = [];
    this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tmp.push({ item_id: i, item_text: data[i].name });
      }
      this.dropdownList = tmp;
    });
  }
```

Comment: How to avoid repeated items, any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Put return in this.dropdownList

```
getData(): void {
    let tmp = [];
    this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tmp.push({ item_id: i, item_text: data[i].name });
      }
      return this.dropdownList = tmp;
    });
  }
console.log(this.dropdownList);
```